# Appending UTF-8 strings to DOMNode in PHP

Tags: php, css, utf-8, html-entities

I have decided that in my particular project I want to deliver the CSS with the HTML using PHP.  My CSS and HTML are collected from various UTF-8 files.  The HTML encoding is preserved in the output, but the CSS encoding isn't.  I'm getting non-ASCII characters escaped as `&#nnnnn;`.  The odd thing is I can `var_dump` the CSS string without the `&#nnnnn;` escapes, but I cannot append it as a `DOMText` or `DOMCDATASection` without it escaping the text.  I have tried various combinations of `htmlentities()`, `html_entities_decode()`, `mb_convert_encoding()`, `mb_detect_encoding()`, `utf8_encode()`, `utf8_decode()`, `createTextNode()`, `createCDATASection()`, but cannot accomplish this simple task.  I don't care how the output is encoded (although UTF-8 would be best), so long as the characters in the CSS display as characters.

My original code was something like:

```
<?php
    $document = new DOMDocument();
    $document->loadHTMLFile("text.html");
    $document->formatOutput = true;
    $xPath = new DOMXpath($document);
    $head = $xPath->query("//html/head")[0];
    $styleElement = $document->createElement("style");
    $styleElement->setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    $styles = $document->createTextNode(file_get_contents("style.css"));
    $styleElement->appendChild($styles);
    $head->appendChild($styleElement);
    echo $document->saveHTML();
?>
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Put a ✧ before this.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";

p::before {
    content: '✧';
}
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style type="text/css">&#65279;p::before {
                content: '&#10023;';
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Put a ✧ before this.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

(Where the browser renders:  `Put a ✧ before this.`)

Desired output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            p::before {
                content: '✧';
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Put a ✧ before this.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

(Where the browser renders:  `✧Put a ✧ before this.`)

(I know there are easier methods of accomplishing the above example with `echo`s etc., but using DOM and XPath makes sense in the broader context.)

Comment: Can you try `createCDATASection` instead of `createTextNode`?

Comment: I tried with `createCDATASection` yesterday, but weirdly it made zero difference...

Comment: Have you tried passing the encoding in the DOMDocument constructor already?

Comment: Just tried it.  No change.
Also now tried adding `@charset "utf-8";` to the CSS.  No luck.

Comment: Further tried adding CDATA tags to the `CDATASection` - HTML entities (unreadable in CSS) still appear, except now none of the CSS is parsed at all.  I've been reading up on CSS encoding.  I could use the CSS character code format, but do so through conversion in PHP, can I?  Side track - why does CSS not use HTML escapes?

Comment: I can get the desired effect using CSS escapes in the .css file, but going through the whole file is more involved than anticipated, and ultimately makes it less readable, so I stopped myself going through it.